# How can i fork the latest state from the mainnet?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat, ganache

I am simulating transactions on uniswap v2 pairs that get deployed but encounter the problem that when forking the mainnet with hardhat it has a delay of roughly 5 blocks meaning i can't access the pairs that just get deployed. i need a better solution than hardhat or ganache or what can i do?

Pair Deploys -> Simulating transactions -> Can't simulate because fork 5 blocks behind.

i already tried forcefully forking from the newest block but the transactions keep failing.

"You are forking from block 18744573, which has less than 6 confirmations, and will affect Hardhat Network's performance."